# Branch IO and react web app: 'Branch' Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, branch.io

I am trying to use branch.io inside of react but it just gives me errors when I'm trying to use it.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
or 
'Branch' Undefined: when I don't set that function to a variable

https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/integrate/

Is how it would normally be used in a website... I just don't understand what to do anymore. :(

```
       let branch = (function(b,r,a,n,c,h,_,s,d,k){if(!b[n]||!b[n]._q){for(;s<_.length;)c(h,_[s++]);d=r.createElement(a);d.async=1;d.src="https://cdn.branch.io/branch-latest.min.js";k=r.getElementsByTagName(a)[0];k.parentNode.insertBefore(d,k);b[n]=h}})(window,document,"script","branch",function(b,r){b[r]=function(){b._q.push([r,arguments])}},{_q:[],_v:1},"addListener applyCode autoAppIndex banner closeBanner closeJourney creditHistory credits data deepview deepviewCta first getCode init link logout redeem referrals removeListener sendSMS setBranchViewData setIdentity track validateCode trackCommerceEvent logEvent disableTracking".split(" "), 0);


branch.init(this.state.key, function(err, data) {
    window.data = data.data_parsed;
    window.branch = branch;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't quite match the instructions given in the branch.io documentation. That minified script already takes care of creating a global `branch` variable, so remove your `let branch =`. Because that's there, it's overwriting the one injected by the script, which is why `branch` is being set to `undefined`.

If you have `eslint` configured and are just worried about `branch` not being defined from its perspective, tack this comment in before the init statement:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
```

Comment: After I removed it I got  Line 30:  'branch' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: function(b,r,a,n,c,h,_,s,d,k){if(!b[n]||!b[n]._q){

.............to many char to paste the whole thing.......
  
branch.init(this.state.key, function(err, data) {
           console.log(data);
        });

Comment: That's just an eslint error. It's not smart enough to know that the line before it _will_ define `branch`. I'd disable the error with an eslint comment. See my edit.

Comment: You are a god among gods... man.  If there is a church or cult that worships you.... Shoot me that address lmao lol